# PDO передача некорректного параметра в подготовленный запрос

Tags: php, pdo

Передаю ошибочный маркер в параметры подготовленного запроса, но в итоге не выбрасывается никакое исключение, возвращает как успешный результат, хотя запись не инсертится в БД, как обойти это?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Action_logs (request_id, msisdn, service_key, action, details, channel) 
          VALUES (:request_id, :msisdn, :service_key, :action, :details, :channel)";

$params = array(
    'request_id'   => XXXX,
    'msisdn'       => XXXX,
    'service_key'  => XXXX,
    'action'       => "Check User Profile Status",
    'details'      => "User profile doesn't exists!",
    'wrong_param'      => "WRONG_PARAM"
);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public function preparedQuery($query, $params)
{
    $thisFunc = basename(__FUNCTION__);

    if (!$this->checkConnection())
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
       $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query)->execute($params);
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e)
    {
        $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, $thisFunc, $this->logsEnabled, 1, "Failed to execute prepared query! " . $e->getMessage() . ", query: " . $query . ", params: " . json_encode($params));
        return false;
    }

    return $stmt;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Вывел ошибку результата выполнения **execute**

```
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1036
    [2] => OCIBindByName: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
 (/usr/local/src/php-7.2.24/ext/pdo_oci/oci_statement.c:348)
)
```

Comment: как вы проверяете результат выполнения, и почему вы ожидаете выброса исключения, вы настроили такое поведение при возникновении ошибки?

Comment: По какой причине сервер должен решить, что это ошибочный параметр? неверный тип данных? ошибка уникальности? ссылочной целостности? что-то ещё? Как именно "ловите" ошибку, каким кодом?

Comment: Ивиняюсь сейчас дополню код. Не подумал

Comment: Стоп... а такого плейсхолдера как `'wrong_param'` в тексте запроса вообще нет.

Comment: Тогда какой смысл в маркерах? или я могу туда что угодно поставить и по ошибке передать не то что нужно? В результате даже не пойму выполнился запрос или нет

Comment: Так я об этом и говорю я вместо :channel специально передал ошибочный плейсхолдер, и ожидал получить ошибку

Comment: Не поленитесь включить General Log и посмотреть, как прошла подстановка, и какой текст запроса был отправлен на сервер... если вообще был отправлен.

Comment: повторюсь еще раз, где вы настраиваете пдо на выброс исключений. Ознакомьтесь с разделом документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.error-handling.php и обратите внимание на `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`, ибо результаты выполнения вы вообще не проверяете.

Comment: у вас там и `$stmt  == false`  на выходе, надо полагать

Comment: Да все верно execute на выходе дает false. Я оиждал что он выбросит исключение, поэтому не обрабатывал его результат

Comment: @teran, У меня настроен при подключении выброс исключений, но я так понимаю сам execute при ошибочном плейсхолдере не выбрасывает исключение а дает на выход stmt false

Comment: Так не было ошибки выполнения-то. Была совершенно штатная ситуация - юзер попросил фигню. С совершенно штатной реакцией - вот тебе false, и делай с ним что хочешь...

Comment: @Akina, да теперь понял спасибо

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос решен!**

При передачи некорректного плейсхолдера, метод `execute()` не выбрасывает исключение а возвращает **false**. Описание ошибки можно получить вызвав метод **PDO::errorInfo** который вернет массив с ошибкой.

**Пример:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1036
    [2] => OCIBindByName: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
 (/usr/local/src/php-7.2.24/ext/pdo_oci/oci_statement.c:348)
)
```